# "NSDictionary+BSONAdditions.h" file not found

Tags: objective-c, objcmongodb

I have created a workspace with ObjcMongoDB as subproject. Then I've built both frameworks and  linked them to my target. By importing `#import <ObjCMongoDB/ObjCMongoDB.h>` I get an error "NSDictionary+BSONAdditions.h" file not found. Have I forgotten something or I've done it completely wrong?

Comment: Did you tell the compiler what path to search to find that header?

Comment: This file is inside ObjCMongoDB framework. All other files are visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the BSONAdditions header is marked Public in the framework target.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes with frameworks Categories are not imported when building. In your 'Build Settings' under 'Other Linker Flags' add a flag '-ObjC' this will import the categories.

Comment: That might fix a runtime error, but not a compiler error.